# sed command to replace the image in kubernetes yaml file

Tags: bash, kubernetes, sed

I have the following Parameters in a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
DOCKER_REGISTRY=gcr.io
GCP_PROJECT=sample
ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION=:7.3.1
```

When i run this command the parameters are all replaced correctly

```
ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE=$DOCKER_REGISTRY/$GCP_PROJECT/elasticsearch$ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION
echo $ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE
gcr.io/sample/elasticsearch:7.3.1
```

I need to replace the ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE on a kubernetes deployment file

> ```
>   containers:
>     - image: {{ELASTICSEARCH}}                                                
>       name: elasticsearch
> ```

So when i run the below command it is not replaced. The issue is because of "/". I tried various sed command but not able to resolve it

YAML_CONTENT=`cat "app-search-application.yaml.template" | sed "s/{{ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE}}/$ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE/g"`

My intension is to dynamically change the image on kubernetes yaml file with the sed command.

Comment: Seems you are not aware of [Helm](https://helm.sh)

Answer (score 3):

The `s` command in `sed` can have different delimiters, if your pattern has `/` use something else in `s` command

```
ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE='gcr.io/sample/elasticsearch:7.3.1'
$ echo "

      containers:
        - image: {{ELASTICSEARCH}}                                                
          name: elasticsearch

" | sed "s|{{ELASTICSEARCH}}|$ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE|"


      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/sample/elasticsearch:7.3.1                                                
          name: elasticsearch
```